# Why is Python Complaining About libcrypto When Importing pysftp on macOS Catalina v10.15.1?

Tags: python, warnings, macos-catalina, pysftp, libcrypto

I just upgraded my MacBook to Catalina v10.15.1. When executing my python script which only does one thing, imports pysftp, I get the following output:

> WARNING: Executing a script that is loading libcrypto in an unsafe
>   way. This will fail in a future version of macOS. Set the
>   LIBRESSL_REDIRECT_STUB_ABORT=1 in the environment to force this into
>   an error.

Could somebody shed some light on why this is occurring? Thank you.

Comment: ever get this resolved,OP?

Comment: Any news on this one, OP? I am thinking it's got something to do with running Python 2.7 locally, but i'm not sure and I can't upgrade to Python 3 yet.