# Google cloud SDK drops a warning on macOS Catalina: Executing a script that is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, macos-catalina, google-cloud-sdk

*Update: Still an issue with version 291.0.0.*

Google Cloud SDK 274.0.1 and some earlier versions drop the following warning on macOS Catalina:

`WARNING: Executing a script that is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way. This will fail in a future version of macOS. Set the LIBRESSL_REDIRECT_STUB_ABORT=1 in the environment to force this into an error.`

To reproduce this error, assuming you have the Google Cloud SDK installed execute the following command: `gcloud --version`

My assumption is that it has something to do with certain Python2 modules inside the latest Google Cloud SDK. And Python2 is no longer supported. [Python2 countdown](https://pythonclock.org) However I am not sure. Perhaps this is related to these issues:

[Why is Python Complaining About libcrypto When Importing pysftp on macOS Catalina v10.15.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58777860/why-is-python-complaining-about-libcrypto-when-importing-pysftp-on-macos-catalin)

and

[Executing a script that is loading libcrypto in an unsafe way on macOS 10.15.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081569/executing-a-script-that-is-loading-libcrypto-in-an-unsafe-way-on-macos-10-15-1)

The answer at the latter is IMHO not the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisiting this issue after getting annoyed by the warning, I realised that my assumption about Python2 was precisely the cause. Python2 is still the standard version on MacOS. So assuming you have Python3 installed on your MacOS distribution set the `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=python3` environment variable as explained in: [Is there a way to use gcloud with Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38113281/is-there-any-way-to-use-gcloud-with-python3) This will get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely right in the reason for the error, I would suggest you to open a report for this over [here](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/new?component=187143&template=800102) so that GCP engineers can address it.

It may take some time to be addressed, however, they should be able to replicate the issue and with this find the solution for it.

Hope you find this helpful!